# Updating values in Sqoop export

Tags: sql, hadoop, export, sqoop

I am using Sqoop export command to export data from HDFS to sql database periodically. Here is my columns and with sample data

```
Date          source     count
01-Feb-2015     xxxx      100
```

What my doubt is If I have data as follows in HDFS

```
01-Feb-2015    xxxx    250
```

I am now using simple export command. Hence after my next export operation database is updated as

```
  Date         source     count
 01-Feb-2015    xxxx      100
 01-Feb-2015    xxxx      250
```

Is there any option in sqoop to achieve following result

```
01-Feb-2015    xxxx   350
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop has the concept of Updates if you specify the update-key. Take a look this section in Sqoop's user guide explaining about [Inserts vs Updates](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_inserts_vs_updates) and how you could perform updates with sqoop-export.